# Why is "text-align: center" not vertically centering elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does the text not get center aligned when placing an image in the li? If I remove the img the text gets centered. I am trying to achieve both being placed centered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="text">Home</span>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAARElEQVR42mNgGAVUAApAfB+I/6Ph+1A5ssB/MvHgsYAugOauH7Vg1IJRC0YtIAI8IsHwR+RY4AHEj4kw/DFU7SggDwAAyTHHV/YXjncAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text">News</span>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean vertically center?Because horizontally it seems you have made them to float left

Comment: Yes, I mean vertically.

Comment: text-align has nothing to do with vertical alignment.

Comment: Oh, ok, then they should have added the word horizontal to that one.

Comment: Because `text-align` only horizontally aligns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text-align` property is used for aligning elements horizontally, not vertically.

Just change your `<ul>` element to a flexbox using `display: flex;` and then use the `align-items` property to vertically center the `<li>` items. Similarly, change your `<li>` elements to a flexbox and use the same property to vertically center the text and the icon.

Also, you need to change your css selector `li hover` to `li:hover`.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above:

```css
ul {list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow: hidden;background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

li {color: white;text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li:hover {background-color: #111;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
   Home
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAARElEQVR42mNgGAVUAApAfB+I/6Ph+1A5ssB/MvHgsYAugOauH7Vg1IJRC0YtIAI8IsHwR+RY4AHEj4kw/DFU7SggDwAAyTHHV/YXjncAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
  </li>
  <li>News</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the image is being also centered as part of the text because *img* elements are displayed inline by default.

Depending on your goal you could have the *img* on it's own *li* or position them absolutely like this:

```
li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
li img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01ecvxfp/

Comment: But in your example the image is not centered vertically.

Comment: Please don't link to code as links can die over time. Edit your answer and insert your executable code into a "code snippet" right here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I included the most important part, which was the CSS, to illustrate my example, should I include everything else?

Comment: Whatever you are going to include, it should be included right here in your answer, not with 3rd party links. There's no reason for Fiddles or CodePens as Stack Overflow has that capability built-in with "code snippets".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center the image use :

```
img{
 margin: auto;
}
```

then center text using

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can achieve vertical and horizontal alignment.

### Flex

As @AndrewL64 explained, you can use `flex` and use the `align-items` property to `center` the element. This is the more modern approach and most recommended for creating a responsive layout.

### Block

You can set the `display` property of the element to `block` and use `margin: 0 auto` to center the element vertically and horizontally.

### Inline-block/inline

Or you can set the `display` property of the element to `inline-block` or `inline` upon which you can use the `text-align: center` property. It is important to note that this property only acts upon the inner content of `block` containers and only affects `inline` or `inline-block` elements.

[This article by Sarah Cope does well to explain the mechanics of such properties](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)